# Why does paste (Unix) add newline automatically?

Tags: unix

I have two files (I renamed file1/2.csv to file1/2.txt):

```
file1     file2
-----     ------
a         1
b         2
...
```

When I use `paste -d "," file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt`. The content of file3.txt is:

```
a
,1
b
,2
```

I wonder why it is not generating the content as below:

```
a,1
b,2
```

Comment: Maybe your file1 has `\r\n` line endings? Run this and post the result: `xxd -p file1`

Comment: @MondKin, thanks for your response. 312030203020302030203020302030200d0a312031203120312030203020 is one line of output of xxd -p file1. When I make the files myself it works. The problem happened when I renamed file1/2.csv to file1/2.txt and tried it.  do not know if it affects it or not.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is `file1` has `\r\n` line endings as you can see in the `xxd` dump:

```
312030203020302030203020302030200d0a312031203120312030203020...
                                ^^^^
                                here
```

You know that's a line ending because `\r == 13 == 0x0d` and `\n == 10 == 0x0a`.

So it seems the `paste` command is not aware of the `\r` just before the line ending, so it lets it at the end of each line from `file1`, but when you look at the content of `file3` you are using a program that interprets `\r` as a line ending.

To solve the problem, you can convert your line endings to `\n` like this:

```
cat file1 | tr -d '\r' > file1-output
```

Or if you have the `dos2unix` program:

```
dos2unix file1
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Is there anyway to change it?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a million @MondKin.